# Github self-deleting recent commits to master

Tags: git, github

I was working on a project yesterday, and made a ton of commits (and pushes) to github. Both on my branch, and on master. When I left, both the remote master and my remote branch were even, with everything I worked during the day.

But when I logged today, all the commits I pushed to remote master yesterday disappeared. It says my last commit was 6 days ago. Meanwhile, my remote branch is correct, still remaining everything I worked on yesterday.

Before leaving, I checked github to see if everything was ok, and it was. I'm 100% sure my commits were correctly pushed to master.

Has this ever happened to anyone else? Do you know why this happened?

Comment: Maybe someone else force-pushed onto your branches?

Comment: There's only one other person who's working with me. And he said he didn't do any pushes. Also, github claims the last commit made to master was made by myself 6 days ago

Comment: If you use Mac OS X, from terminal (Mac) type `history` to see old commands, to see what happen. If your GitHub repository is public, you should share link.

Comment: @DoNhuVy I'm on ubuntu, what command should I type? And the repository is private.

Comment: You still use command `history`. Check history on Ubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/624848/view-history-of-commands-ran-in-terminal

Comment: @DoNhuVy history showed everything correct. My last git command was git push origin master, and my local master is correct (i just checked)

Comment: this might be a problem with GitHub itself. They had similar issues in the past when due to the outage on their side they were losing commits.